# Nomenclature in 2 Columns

Tags: symbols, glossaries, multicol, columns, nomenclature

I am trying to get the nomenclature into two nice columns. At the moment, when I use multicol, there is a space at the top of the first column,for the automatic title. I've deleted the auto title and just put in a standard one so I can center it. However the space is still retained for a title in the first column while the second colum begins at the top of the page. I'd like both columns to begin one the same line. How can I modify this to do that??

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{verbatim}%to make comments
\usepackage{multicol}%for multiple columns



%Nomenclature Package
%----------------------------------------------
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
%% this modifies item separation:
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{8pt}
%% This will add the subgroups for Nomenclature
%----------------------------------------------

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{% 
  \item[\bfseries
  \ifstrequal{#1}{A}{Stuff}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{B}{Other Stuff}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{C}{More Stuff}{}}}%
]}
%End Nomenclature Package (don'tforget \printnomenclature)
%----------------------------------------------


\title{Nomenclatures Example}
\author{}
\date{\today}



\begin{document}
\maketitle

\newpage


%% This will add the units
%----------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\nomunit}[1]{%
\renewcommand{\nomentryend}{\hspace*{\fill}#1}}
%----------------------------------------------
\begin{center}
\textbf{Nomenclature}
\end{center}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\renewcommand{\nomname}{}%change title
\printnomenclature
\end{multicols}
\nomenclature[A]{$m$}{Mass \nomunit{[Kg]}}
\nomenclature[A]{$V$}{Velocity \nomunit{[m/s]}}
\nomenclature[A]{$t$}{Time \nomunit{[s]}}
\nomenclature[B, 03]{${R}$}{Real Numbers}
\nomenclature[B, 02]{${C}$}{Complex Numbers}
\nomenclature[B, 01]{${H}$}{Quaternions}
\nomenclature[C]{$V$}{Constant Volume}
\nomenclature[A]{$\rho$}{Friction Index}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a section title for the nomenclature, but you can change it if you so prefer. The trick is to add the title in the optional argument to `\begin{multicols}`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{verbatim}%to make comments
\usepackage{multicol}%for multiple columns
\usepackage{etoolbox}

%Nomenclature Package
%----------------------------------------------
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\setlength{\nomitemsep}{8pt}

\newcommand{\nomunit}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\nomentryend}{\hspace*{\fill}#1}%
}

\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{% 
  \item[\bfseries
  \ifstrequal{#1}{A}{Stuff}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{B}{Other Stuff}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{C}{More Stuff}{}}}%
]}

\patchcmd{\thenomenclature}
 {\section*{\nomname}}
 {\begin{multicols}{2}[\section*{\nomname}]}
 {}{}
\appto\endthenomenclature{\end{multicols}}
\setlength{\columnsep}{2pc}
%----------------------------------------------

\title{Nomenclatures Example}
\author{}
\date{\today}



\begin{document}
\maketitle

\newpage

\printnomenclature

\nomenclature[A]{$m$}{Mass \nomunit{[kg]}}
\nomenclature[A]{$V$}{Velocity \nomunit{[m/s]}}
\nomenclature[A]{$t$}{Time \nomunit{[s]}}
\nomenclature[B, 03]{${R}$}{Real Numbers}
\nomenclature[B, 02]{${C}$}{Complex Numbers}
\nomenclature[B, 01]{${H}$}{Quaternions}
\nomenclature[C]{$V$}{Constant Volume}
\nomenclature[A]{$\rho$}{Friction Index}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For the bad column break, you have to be confident on your luck.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the output is looking great. I'm having a little trouble with it compiling though. The \patchcmd is giving me some errors. I can't really see why but I'm getting an unexpected close group after the \begin{multicols}, an unclosed open group { found at \end{multicols},  unexpected \end{multicols}, and an unexpected close group }   Any idea why?

Comment: @gravity121 Sorry, but I pasted the exact code I used to produce the picture.

Comment: Ok, it's still giving errors but it's also compiling just as you showed so maybe it's just a compiler issue. Thanks for your help. The result is just what I was looking for ;-)